# How to solve assembly ID error when serializing enum in C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, binaryformatter

I am trying to serialize my own enum with the binaryformatter, but i keep getting an error that says that there is no assembly id.
My enum looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public enum MyEnum{NONE, OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3};
```

This is my code for the serializing:

```
public class Binder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        return Type.GetType(typeName);
    }

    public override void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = "";
        typeName = serializedType.FullName;
    }
}

public static byte[] GetBytes<T>(this T c)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Binder = new Binder();
        bf.Serialize(m, c);
        return m.ToArray();
    }
}
```

The full error:

Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
No assembly ID for object type 'program.MyEnum'.

Comment: `program.MyEnum` seems incorrect if proper naming conventions are being followed, are you sure it's not `Program.MyEnum`, or just `MyEnum` (If **not** defined *inside* the class `Program`)?

Comment: The enum is inside the namespace program so lowercase is correct in this case.

Comment: Gotcha, Is there more information in the stack trace?

Comment: Here is the useful part of the stack trace: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KSG4azVX)

Comment: Is all of the code defined in the same assembly?

Comment: Yes it is all in the same assembly.

Comment: In `BindToName`, try setting `assemblyName` to `null`.

Comment: Well that fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the error states:

> No assembly ID for object type 'program.MyEnum'.

The `assemblyName` parameter of `BindToName` seems suspect.

A quick search didn't turn up a lot, except [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1101106/How-to-Serialize-Across-Assemblies-with-the-Binary) does mention:

> ...if you leave the assembly-name as NULL, the normal assembly name will
>   be written into the stream, which is why we set a non-null value (you
>   could use a zero-length string)

So I assume that setting `assemblyName` to `null`, rather than an empty string, would cause the Binding to resolve to the current (normal?) assembly.